# addClass & removeClass in nav.php

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have a nav.php in my root that I call within each page using

This way I can edit in one file and the change takes effect throughout the whole site. I am trying to removeClass on a mouse click and addClass on newly click menu item. Below is the code, and I just can't get it to work.

```
<script>
    $('li').click(function(){
        $('li.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Here is the URL

http://newriverreleasing.com

Thanks

Comment: The source code in the link you provided does not have your above script in it anywhere.

Comment: actually your code works fine for me

Comment: Still not working for me even after I added $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with this...

The query selector $('li') will surely match more than one element on the page, so you'll need to iterate through all of them and add the click() function, something like:

```
$('li').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function(thisLi) {
    // assuming there is only one li.active...
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    thisLi.addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Also, you need to load this onto the elements that it matches by putting it in a $(document).ready() function, or similar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').each(function() {
      $(this).click(function(thisLi) {
        // assuming there is only one li.active...
        $('li.active').removeClass('active');
        thisLi.addClass('active');
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Even if there are multiple active LIs `$('li.active').removeClass('active')` would remove the active class from all of them. The selector would match them all and they would all have removeClass applied to them.

Comment: oh, huh.  does that also go for $('li').click() ?  i think i have needed the iterator in the past to add a trigger.

Comment: Yes it does. Go try it out and clean up some of your old JS!